# Trying to identify a bunch of parts from sets I had as a child 20 years ago

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I'd love some help to identify some/any of the kits I have from the following pictures of parts I have:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Most of this LEGO would've been purchased around 1999 if that helps but I think it could range from 1995 through to 2002 ish.

I have many thousands of pieces from my childhood collection these are some of the more unique and I figure more easily to identify pieces.

Comment: I like how the photos don't have wasted space! The big electronic item in the second photo with 3 black buttons is from Insectoids <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x239#T=C>.

Comment: The wings with circuitry, top right of the second photo, are mostly (but not entirely) from Insectoids: <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30230px1>

Comment: According to BrickLink, the pattern on the round 2x2 on the left of the first photo was only in set 7311 <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4150px3>

Comment: Two yellow tiles near the top of the first photo are from Aquazone (including Aquanauts and Aquasharks) <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx11&colorID=3>

Comment: The big white wedge pieces were in 17 sets in white <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3586&colorID=1>

Comment: The tail at the bottom of the first photo with the eagle with tye yellow stripe was in 2 Technic sets <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2340pb022&in=S>

Comment: Wow thanks everyone! This is very helpful info!

Comment: These bring back some memories. Back when Lego boxes where still creative and not just another iteration of the latest marvel movie.

Comment: The electronic one with the buttons belongs together to the same theme as the translucent wings, I think. I have many of your parts as well. The wings and the one with the buttons are relatively new (compared to the others). I bought these when I was much older, compared to the others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These parts belong to a ton of different sets.

**1st picture**

- Black Engine, Smooth Large, 1 x 2 Thin Top Plate can be found in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4868a&colorID=11&in=A).
- Black Tail with Rounded Top, Aquazone Aquashark Blue Shark with Red 'X' Pattern belong to [one of three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3587pb02&colorID=11&in=A).
- Slope 33 3 x 2 with Exploriens Logo Pattern was available in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298p10&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Hinge Train Gate 2 x 4 with Satellite Orbiting Earth Screen Pattern (Sticker) - Set 6458 is part of [Satellite with Astronaut (6458)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6458-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set:

[image]

- Light Gray Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Dynamite Pattern was in [40 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bp03&colorID=9&in=A).
- Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Alien Egg Pattern (Magnetic Sticker) - Exploriens Sets was in [8 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bpb0030&colorID=11&in=A).
- Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Dinosaur Skeleton and Bone Pattern (Magnetic Sticker) - Exploriens Sets was in [8 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bpb0036&colorID=11&in=A) too.
- Tile 2 x 2 with Spyrius Blue Screen with Plus Sign and Silver and Red Panel Pattern seen in [15 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bp51&colorID=11&in=A).
- Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 Door with Slot and Spyrius Pattern been in [3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4346px15&colorID=11&in=A).
- Yellow Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Underwater Navigation Pattern seen in [8 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx11&colorID=3&in=A).
- White Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Zebra Stripes Pattern been in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4150px15&colorID=1&in=A)
- Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Blue and Yellow Controls Pattern (Ice Planet) available in [14 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bp61&in=S).
- Red Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Number 2 Bold White and Stripes Pattern been in [2 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bpb0006&colorID=5&in=A).
- White Tile 2 x 2 with White Arrow in Blue Circle Pattern have been in [17 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bp50&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Brick 1 x 3 with Radio and Dual Cassette Pattern Dark Pink/Green (Sticker) - Set 5895 has incorrectly applied sticker and has been available in [Villa Belville (5895)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5895-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

- White Slope 33 3 x 2 with Number 1 Pattern has been part of [8 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298p54&colorID=1&in=A).
- Black Slope 45 2 x 2 with Yellow Grille Pattern has been in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3039p10&colorID=11&in=A).
- Black Slope 33 3 x 2 with Number 4 Pattern been in [8 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298pb007&colorID=11&in=A).
- White Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with 'POLICE' Red Line Pattern has been in [20 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx29&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Arrow Short Yellow with Black Border Pattern been in [18 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bp13&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Slope 75 2 x 1 x 3 - Open Stud with Shuttle and Blue/Red Circle Pattern, Model Right (Sticker) - Set 6614 AND Panel 1 x 2 x 1 with Blue -V- and two Red Lines Pattern (Sticker) - Set 6614
  are unique to [Launch Evac 1 (6614)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6614-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

- Assembly which feature distinctive Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Flame and Sand Green Border Pattern belong to [Red Planet Cruiser (7311)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7311-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set:

[image]

- Blue Slope 33 3 x 2 with Number 2 Pattern been in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298p55&colorID=7&in=A).
- Blue Slope 33 3 x 2 with Ice Planet Logo Pattern been in [7 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298p61&colorID=7&in=A).
- Windscreen 6 x 4 x 1 1/3 with Bottom Tabs and Hollow Studs with Number 7 and Blue, White and Red Swirls Pattern (Stickers) - Set 8223 AND Panel 1 x 2 x 1 with Number 7 on Right and Blue, White and Red Swirls Pattern (Sticker) - Set 8223 as name suggests is unique to [Hydrofoil 7 (8223)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8223-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set

[image]

- One of the red tails is from [Aero Hawk II (8812)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8812-1)

[image]

- Other Red pieces are from [Eagle Stunt Flyer (6615)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6615-1)

[image]

- Tile 1 x 4 with 3 White Stars Pattern has been available in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2431px6&colorID=7&in=A).

**2nd picture**

- Flag 7 x 3 with Rod with Space Port Solar Array with '2000-XZ' Pattern (Sticker) - Sets 6454 / 6456 / 6458 been in [three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30292pb001&colorID=14&in=A). Conveniently, these are mentioned in part description.
- Panel 3 x 5 Solar/Clip-On/Deltoid with Reflective Trapezoid Pattern (Sticker) been in [7 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30034pb01&colorID=1&in=A).
- Electric, Light & Sound 4 x 20 x 5 Insectoid Stinger have been part of [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x239&colorID=10&in=A).
- Both [Wing Insectoid Large with Arm Hinge and Circuitry Pattern Left (Print on Top, Tip on Left, Logo at Back Edge)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30230px1#T=C&C=14)
  and [Wing Insectoid Large with Arm Hinge and Circuitry Pattern Right (Print on Top, Tip on Right, Logo at Back Edge)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30230px2#T=C) been in same [5 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30230px2#T=C).
- Windscreen 10 x 4 x 2 1/3 Canopy with Blue Outlines and Red Square Pattern
  was in just [Deep Sea Predator (6155)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6155-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

- While Windscreen 10 x 4 x 2 1/3 Canopy with Black Aquasharks Pattern is seen in the same set it has appeared in [3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2507pb01&colorID=18&in=A) overall.
- Trans-Neon Green Cylinder Hemisphere 4 x 4 Multifaceted was in [9 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30208&colorID=16&in=A).
- Trans-Neon Green Dish 6 x 6 Inverted (Radar) Webbed - Type 2 (underside attachment positions at 90 degrees) was in [5 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4285b&colorID=16&in=A).
- Trans-Green Dish 5 x 5 Scala was in just [3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6942&colorID=20&in=A), all from Belville theme, despite the use of "Scala" naming.
- Trans-Light Blue Windscreen 4 x 4 x 4 1/3 Helicopter with Coast Guard Logo Pattern (Sticker) - Set 6342 as name suggest is specific to [Beach Rescue Chopper (6342)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6342-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set.

[image]

- Trans-Dark Blue Windscreen 6 x 6 Octagonal Canopy with Axle Hole has been part of [7 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2418b&colorID=14&in=A).

**3rd picture**

- White Tile, Round 8 x 8 seen in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6177&colorID=1&in=A).
- Both White Wedge, Plate 7 x 12 Wing Left and White Wedge, Plate 7 x 12 Wing Right have been in [17 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3585&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Wedge, Plate 8 x 6 x 2/3 with Grille has been in just [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30036&colorID=1&in=A).
- White Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud has been in whooping [472 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3062b&colorID=1&in=A).

Comment: I think I'm only missing a couple of tiles I find hard to ID.

Comment: +1 for the effort involved in finding all this info.

Comment: Thanks heaps for all your hard work on tracking these sets down! It's like a walk down memory lane seeing all these sets that I had when I was a kid. I'm aiming to assemble them all now that I've got my own house and display cabinet to proudly show 'em off!

Comment: @joshendy what a coincidence. I have found a box of missing parts from my childhood sets and just have been working on them for last couple of days. Some of the parts were easy to ID because of these sets I had as well.

Answer (score 3):

Give a man a fish and he will eat for the day, teach a man to fish and he will eat for life.

Since its a few months old you probably have this figured out already. But, if not, here is what I learned in the last 6 weeks sitting on my rec room floor with thousands of bricks (3 large plastic tubs). Also from the 90's and early 2000's. Besides my sons sets my neighbor gave me a big black garbage bag full of bricks from his kids. He was on his way to the garbage can. He offered so I took them. Here is the clue - on the back of almost every brick is an id number. Pick the most unusual pieces and use it to track your sets. Google the number starting with Lego then the number. [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) has been my best reference so far but Lego recommends [BrickOwl](https://www.brickowl.com). On Bricklink you will get a lot of info and thousands of people around the world selling them in their little stores. There is a "Item Appears In" link that will direct you to a list of Lego sets that contain the part. They sort it by color and date. Then you have to hunt it down. Once you find it, they will give you inventories for the set as well as assembly instructions in PDF's.

Doing this I have identified 50 plus sets, reconstituted 25 plus and fully reassembled 26. Some rather large. So those little stores on Bricklink and BrickOwl charge pennies for most pieces but be leery of those that charge large shipping fees and adding handling charges. My mailman was delivering my packages, mostly small, in plastic tubs.

Good luck, it's addicting.

Comment: "Lego recommends Brickowl.com" citation needed, keeping in mind TLG owns Bricklink now.